# Solving systems of symbolic equations between two block matrices in sympy?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math, equation-solving

Assume that I have two symbolic block matrices, below called `N` and `M`. Each entry of the block matrices corresponds to the other, so that we should have (analytically) `N.blocks[0,0] = M.blocks[0,0]`. Is it possible to solve the resulting system of equations for the matrices in `N`, i.e. `A`, `B`, and `C`?

```
import sympy as sym

# Create matrices for the full blockmatrix
A = sym.MatrixSymbol('A',1,1)
B = sym.MatrixSymbol('B',1,1)
C = sym.MatrixSymbol('C',1,1)

# Coefficient matrices, assumed known
M1 = sym.MatrixSymbol('A',1,1)
M2 = sym.MatrixSymbol('B',1,1)
M3 = sym.MatrixSymbol('C',1,1)

# Create a zero entry
Z = sym.ZeroMatrix(1,1)

# Create the 2-by-2 block matrix
S = sym.BlockMatrix([
    [A,Z],
    [B,C]])

# Take its inverse
Sinv = S.inverse()

# Then form the dot product with its transpose
# This is the block matrix with our matrix equations
N = sym.block_collapse(Sinv*Sinv.transpose())

# Simplify the results
N = N.simplify()

# Create the (symmetric) target coefficient matrix
M = sym.BlockMatrix([
    [M1,M2.transpose()],
    [M2,M3]])

# Is there some way to solve the resulting system of equations?
```